# Have there been tests used to measure one's perception of how creative something is?

Tags: perception, measurement, creativity

I'm trying to think of ways to 'measure' creativity from an objective standpoint. One way that I can think of is to show multiple different 'creations' to observers and to ask them to rate the creativity level of each creation.

But I am wondering if this would be an unreliable way to do it. For one thing, I am sure that creativity depends on how *novel* the thing is *to the perceiver*. For example, suppose I took a Harry Potter book and changed all instances of the name 'Harry Potter' to 'Jim Jones'. Someone who has never read Harry Potter before might read this book and think it extraordinarily creative, whereas a Harry Potter fan would immediately recognize it as a knock-off.

But I am also wondering if there is a certain talent for understanding what is creative and what isn't. There are people who 'get' art and can produce creative works of art, and there are people who find this to be difficult.

Nonetheless, I was wondering if any such objective measures of creativity perception exist, and how reliable they might be?

Comment: Related: http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/q/10458/8657